# Great Plains query to get GL codes

Tags: sql, dynamics-gp

I need to write a `SQL` query to extract `GL` information (`codes, descriptions, associated company`) from Great Plains.  Is there a site that can describe what each table does, how they are linked, etc?  Or even better a site with an available `SQL` query to simply list all the `GLs` to get me started?  I'm new to `GP`, never did any development or work in it and I don't even know where to start due to the `cryptic table names`.

Answer (score 1):

The GP back end is not the most stright forward to query as every company is in a unique database.

```
select      ACTINDX
    ,       ACTNUMBR_1
    ,       ACTNUMBR_2 
    ,       ACTNUMBR_3
    ,       ACTNUMBR_4 
    ,       ACTNUMBR_5
    ,       ACTALIAS
    ,       MNACSGMT
    ,       ACCTTYPE 
    ,       ACTDESCR
from GL00100
```

The above code will give you the GL account listing in addition the the ACTINDX (OID). I'd recommend starting with the following links as a starting resource for more complex queries:

http://www.gp-dynamics.com/dynamics-gp-tips-and-tricks.asp

http://victoriayudin.com/gp-tables/